# Is that possible to set a limit size / length to publish SNS AWS messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I know it is easy to set a limit size of a SQS message using the att "Maximum Message Size". I can set like 32kb, 20kb etc. I can't find similar option in SNS. Is it even possible? Maybe using policy rules or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNS has max payload limit of 256KB. Currently, it does not support customized threshold as you suggested.